# Open Source Malware Scanner/Cleaner

Tags: malware, antimalware, opensource

What is the best Open Source Malware Scanner/Cleaner?  Malware-bites is good but it requires licensing for companies.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever open source antiviruses are discussed, people always end up mentioning ClamAV ( http://www.clamav.net/index.html ). So I don't know if other ones have gained significant traction, but this one certainly seems to be the most popular one.

Answer (score 0):

If free-as-in-beer is good enough, Microsoft supply one-time scanners, and Microsoft Security Essentials is free for home and small business use (up to 10 machines).

For a one-time scan, use Windows Defender Offline for a complete bootable scanning environment:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline

Alternatively Microsoft Safety Scanner (essentially 10-day limited antivirus):

http://www.microsoft.com/security/scanner/en-us/default.aspx

For a home or small business antivirus, you can use Microsoft Security Essentials:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/business/products/security-essentials

**Licencing Terms May Change:** Check the current EULA.

However at the time of writing the EULA says this:

> 1. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS
>
>    a.   Home Use. If you are a home user, then you may install and use any number of copies of the software on
>      your personal devices for use by people who reside in your household.
>
>    b.   Small Business. If you operate a small business, then you may
>      install and use the software on up to ten (10) devices in your
>      business.

Other vendors also offer offline scanning solutions.